# Adding text above horizontalscrollview (Android)

Tags: android, text

So I want to display a line of text centred at the top of the screen above a horizontal scroll view.
Basically the top line of text is going to display the tuning you are in, and underneath it will display the horizontal scroller, and underneath that I will be adding in images later, I have tried a few different things but all of them seem to push the horizontal scroller off the screen. Any suggestions on how I can do this?
Here is the code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/near_black">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/e_button"
    android:text="@string/E" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/white">
</Button>
```

And this continues on with a few buttons and I close off everything.
So any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the *root* `LinearLayout` use a vertical orientation:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black">
```

Then adding a `Textview` on top of the `HorizontalScrollView` should work.